# layout-align="center" not working Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, cardview

I am trying to center align the Input/Edit Text in the card using the layout-align attribute. However due to my ignorance and infancy (started learning today), I am unable to figure out why the Edit Text won't get center aligned inside this card View.

```
<div flex="50" layout="row" layout-align="center">
    <md-card flex="50">
        <md-input-container layout-align="center center" class="md-block" flex="50">
            <input required type="text" placeholder="Observation Number" ng-model="learningCenter.observations.obsNum" />
        </md-input-container>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

**Demo here**: https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zBQZLW?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the material guideline, you need to place the input-container in a row element,

```
<md-card flex="50">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-input-container  flex="50">
            <input required type="text" placeholder="Observation Number" ng-model="learningCenter.observations.obsNum" />
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/jVMNOB)**

Comment: Does that mean, if I have 10 input-containers and a button, I'll have to put them all in separate divs with layout=row?

Comment: @UmerFarooq yes you need to

Comment: I have tried it out already and it seems to work but isn't it extra work for the compiler/renderer in the browser which might result in a performance hit (which might not be noticable in certain areas apparently)? Plus it also seems very tedious and extra work

Comment: That's how you would do even if you use bootstrap

Comment: oh ok Never tried that either. Seems like Rendering mechanism is different here compared to how MObile Frameworks render views. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the `md-input-container` you should surround it by a `div` with a `layout="row"`. This will do the trick to align it horizontally, however in order to align it vertically you need to give your `div` some `height`. Your `md-card` should look something like this: (note that you can give a `height` of your choice depending on how you want the `md-input-container` to align vertically)

```
<md-card flex="50">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="min-height: 100%">
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="50">
            <input required type="text" placeholder="Observation Number"
                ng-model="learningCenter.observations.obsNum"/>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/mOrbRJ) is a working fork of your code.